# Where can you set up 301 redirect on Parrallel Helms

Tags: web-hosting, 301-redirect, multiple-domains

I need to do a 301 redirect on Parrallel Helms cPanel like software.
For the life of me I can not find it, the hosting company Hostworx doesn't answer my emails. Does anyone know where in Parrallel Helms that I can setup a 301 redirect?

Is Parrallel Helms a common substitute for cPanel?

Comment: Do they not have support?  Is there no forum?  If not, why would you use something like this?

Comment: My client is using them. They seemed to sign up via their website. They don't reply to any of their support emails I sent them

Comment: Well if they don't support their own product, your client can't expect you to.